# i need an alternative solution for ng-change

Tags: angularjs

i tried calling the values using ng-change between two different ng-models. it works.
but the data is parsed to the other ng-model only if the data is changed, is there any alternate solution where i can have the data in both ng-models before changing data

I tried something like this

HTML

```
<input ng-model="customer.name" ng-change='tripsheet.customer_name=customer.name;'>
<input ng-model="tripsheet.customer_name"  type="text" class="form-control input-lg"     placeholder="Customer Name">
```

JS

```
 $scope.customer = {
  name:$scope.customers[$scope.whichItem].name,
  address:$scope.customers[$scope.whichItem].address,
  phone:$scope.customers[$scope.whichItem].phone
}
```

i want the routeParams data in both the above ng-models.

Answer (score 1):

With something like this in your controller?

```
$scope.customer = {
    name: "Tom" 
};

$scope.tripsheet = {
    customer_name: $scope.customer.name
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tGrw6NZVMq9X08RlThdu?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

@mainguy's answer is a very good approach.

Or alternatively you can go with $watch instead of ng-change.
initialize a watcher for the model object

```
$scope.$watch('customer.name', customerNameChanged);
```

and define the function

```
function customerNameChanged() {
    if(!$scope.tripsheet)
        $scope.tripsheet = {};
    $scope.tripsheet.customer_name = $scope.customer.name
}
```

ng-change triggers only when there is a user interaction and the data is changed.

$watch is triggered when the model object is changed programmatically and also when they’re being defined the first time